# Can't get Scroll/Layout to work

Tags: qt

I am trying to force a container size of 200x100, while adding child controls that are spread over an area larger than 200x100. I expect to have a scroll bar when I exceed the size of the viewport, but the entire container window gets resized.

how do I force a container size of 200x100 and still get scroll bars that'll allow me to scroll down and see the rest of the content?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QGridLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget container;
    container.setGeometry(QRect(600,300,200,100));

    QGridLayout layout(&container);

    QPushButton *aa = new QPushButton(QString("a"));
    aa->setGeometry(QRect(10,10,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(aa, 0, 0);

    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton(QString("b"));
    b->setGeometry(QRect(10,40,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(b, 1, 0);

    QPushButton *c = new QPushButton(QString("c"));
    c->setGeometry(QRect(10,70,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(c, 2, 0);

    QPushButton *d = new QPushButton(QString("d"));
    d->setGeometry(QRect(10,100,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(d, 3, 0);

    QPushButton *e = new QPushButton(QString("e"));
    e->setGeometry(QRect(10,130,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(e, 4, 0);

    QPushButton *f = new QPushButton(QString("f"));
    f->setGeometry(QRect(10,160,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(f, 5, 0);

    QPushButton *g = new QPushButton(QString("g"));
    g->setGeometry(QRect(10,190,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(g, 6, 0);

    QPushButton *h = new QPushButton(QString("h"));
    h->setGeometry(QRect(10,220,100,30));
    layout.addWidget(h, 7, 0);

    QScrollArea area;


    area.setLayout(&layout);
    area.setWidget(&container);
    area.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the size of the `QScrollArea` using `setGeometry()`, then use `area.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed)`.